# Apache POI 4.0: XSSFColor from java.awt.Color

Tags: java, colors, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

`org.apache.poi 4.0` removed the `XSSFColor` constructor that just uses `java.awt.Color`. In `org.apache.poi 3.7` it was very easy to create the object by just writing

```
Color inputColor = Color.RED;
XSSFColor test = new XSSFColor(inputColor);
```

However, this constructor no longer works in 4.0. The documentation at https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html shows several other constructors, but ideally i want to change as few lines as possible.

So, my question is, what is the best way to create an `XSSFColor` from a `java.awt.Color` now (in apache poi 4.0)?

---

As requested in the comments, here is my test code using the suggestion `style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.RED, null));`
Opening this with LibreOffice 6.1 yields an Error (Attempt to repair, which then fails). Commented out the POI 3.7 version which works normally.

```
@Test
public void testPOI40() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet fSheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet("new Sheet");
    XSSFRow hRow = fSheet.createRow((short) 0);
    //header
    String[] astrHeaders = new String[]{"Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4"};
    for (int col = 0; col < astrHeaders.length; col++) {
        XSSFCell cell = hRow.createCell((short) col);
        XSSFCellStyle tempHeaderStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
        tempHeaderStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
        tempHeaderStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cell.setCellValue(astrHeaders[col]);
        cell.setCellStyle(tempHeaderStyle);
    }        
    //body
    Double[] astrContent = new Double[]{1.3, 0.3, 0.87, 1.0};     
    Color[] colors = new Color[] {Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.WHITE,Color.GREEN};        
    XSSFRow fRow = fSheet.createRow((short) 1);
    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < 4; iCol++) {
        XSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((short) iCol);
        XSSFCellStyle tempBodyStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) workbook.createCellStyle();
        cell.setCellValue(astrContent[iCol]);
        //working with POI 3.17
        //tempBodyStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(colors[iCol]));
        tempBodyStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(colors[iCol],null));
        tempBodyStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cell.setCellStyle(tempBodyStyle);
    }        
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("testfile.xlsx"));
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);
    workbook.write(bos);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

**Solution:** 
Replaced `fileout.close();` with `bos.close();` and it works. So `tempBodyStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.RED,null));` as suggested in the comments by Alex Richter is a good solution & will accept this as answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however the table resulting from the first method is reported as damaged when trying to open it. The second method fails because `setColor(Color) has protected access in ExtendedColor`.

Comment: Sorry but `style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.RED, null));` works for me using `apache poi 4.0.0` and creating `XSSFWorkbook` from scratch. Please show minimal complete verifiable example which shows where it fails.

Comment: Thank you, I added my test for your suggestion to the main post now.

Comment: Just to clarify, the code doesn't cause an error, but the output file cannot be read (but the version using POI 3.7, see commented out section, is readable)

Comment: The damaging has nothing to do with the colors. You are wrapping the FileOutputStream in an BufferedOutputStream but do closing then only the inner FileOutputStream but not the BufferedOutputStream. Do `workbook.write(bos); bos.close();` and it will work. At least it works for me then. It might had worked in former `apache poi` versions because `Workbook.write` had closed all streams when it was ready. This it does not more.

Comment: You are right! Never looked there because it worked without causing problems with POI 3.7, but the missing `bos.close()` is indeed the culprit. If you want to put `style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.RED, null));`as answer i would certainly accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are wrapping the `FileOutputStream` in an `BufferedOutputStream` but do closing then only the inner `FileOutputStream` but not the `BufferedOutputStream`, then the `BufferedOutputStream` remains open and the file will not have all bytes in.

That's why the damaging of the file.

So the damaging has noting to do with constructing the `XSSFColor`. The constructor `style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.RED, null));` works.

Do instead:

```
...
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("testfile.xlsx"));
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);
workbook.write(bos); 
bos.close();
workbook.close();
...
```

It might had worked in former apache poi versions because `XSSFWorkbook.write` had closed all streams when it was ready. This it does not more. And this is correct because `write` should not closing streams.

But since `POIXMLDocument` implements `java.io.Closeable` at least `workbook.close()` should closing all streams. But that also it does not. So explicitly closing all streams is necessary in `apache poi 4.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks again. Could you maybeadd the line `tempBodyStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.RED,null));` in the answer for people who just look for a oneliner to replace the old method (and are not intersted in my example)?